# Upper bound on the number of sets in a subcover of an open cover: only finite sets?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

This is for the real line only.

> For which compact sets can you set an upper bound on the number of
> sets in a subcover of an open cover?

We can definitely impose an upper bound for finite sets, but are there any infinite sets for which we can impose an upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no upper bound on the number of sets in a subcover of an open cover when the given compact set is infinite.

---

Suppose $S\in\Bbb R$ is infinite.

Select $n$ points in $S$. Let $d$ be the minimum distance between any two of the selected points. Consider the open cover $\mathcal C=\{(s-\frac d3, s+\frac d3)\cap S\mid s\in S\}$. Since the length of each interval $(s-\frac d3, s+\frac d3)$ is smaller than $d$, each interval can cover at most one of the selected points. Hence any subcover of $\mathcal C$ must contain at least $n$ such intervals so as to cover the selected $n$ points.

Since $n$ can be arbitrary large, there can be no upper bound on the number of sets in a subcover given an open cover of $S$.

---

By the way, the proof above does not require $S$ be compact.

Comment: Why does "remaining points that are not covered by the selected opens must not have a limit point" imply "they must be finite"?

Comment: And regarding the last sentence, are you saying every compact set has finitely many limit points?

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck on this one for the past 2 days.

Comment: @erfgerwge You are welcome!